# withdrawing OP token from Optimism

Tags: tokens

I think Coinbase accidentally deposited my purchased OP token onto the Optimism network (!!)

I confirmed this on etherscan. I never selected the optimism network (that isn't even an option in coinbase). so that's pretty bad... but this isn't about me complaining...

how do I get them back? The optimism bridge doesn't allow for you to select the OP token for withdrawals, even on the official bridge, which supposedly supports all tokens. What gives? How do I get my OP back?

-Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap to eth using uniswap or 1inch on the OP network and then just bridge the eth back.

Answer (score 0):

coinbase support is absolutely useless, they wont help much.
as @Sam suggested , swap OP to ETH ot WETH and then bridge back to mainnet.